# How to display emails in an angular app like it gets displayed in an email client

Tags: html, css, angular, email, gmail

I am currently trying to develop a web app to display EMails to the user. It is important for me that the emails get displayed like they get in an email client (e.g. gmail).
I use the gmail api to import emails to my database then I get the messageparts from the emails into my angular app.
The problem is that I am not able to display html emails with the propert styling. It seems like html tags get used correclty but the original styling seems to be lost

I am using angular 7, and spring boot. To collect the Emails I use the gmail api and import them into a postgresql database. I tried to use iframes so my app styling doesn't get in the way of the email styling but it gets displayed the same way.

How I prepare the emails

```java
private String getMessageContent(Message message) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            if(message.getPayload().getParts() != null) {
                handleEmailMainContent(message.getPayload().getParts(), stringBuilder);
                byte[] bodyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(stringBuilder.toString());
                return new String(bodyBytes, "UTF-8");
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           System.out.println("UnsupportedEncoding: " + e.toString());
            return message.getSnippet();
        }
    }

    private void handleEmailMainContent(List<MessagePart> messageParts, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
        for (MessagePart messagePart : messageParts) {
            switch (messagePart.getMimeType()) {
                case "text/plain":
                    handleMimeTypeTextPlain(messagePart, stringBuilder);
                    break;
                case "text/html":
                    handleMimeTypeTextHtml(messagePart, stringBuilder);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: selectedEmail.mainContent is the String I build above

#### Example

The content inside mainContent are phishing emails I try to collect and display. The example is a html email I try to display.
I ommited  the links and most of the spam content.

---------- Forwarded message ---------
Von: emailaddress
Date: Fr., 10. Mai 2019 um 22:06 Uhr
Subject: Name, Give mom the gifts she wants
To: emailaddress

image
Become part of the Heally family on *Facebook*
link
!
- LET'S TALK
Celebraing Mom
*...*
Moms run the world. They literally give us life, take on one of the hardest
roles, and do it all without an end to their workday or any time off. While
moms deserve to be celebrated year-round, Mother’s Day is a special time to
make sure they know they’re loved and appreciated.
LEARN MORE
link

Looking for CBD only Products?
PROMO CODE: *SAVECBD20*
link
CBD 20% OFF
link
Give mom gifts that she actually wants.
Shop the Marketplace

-ommited SPAM-

You are receiving this email because you or your medical provider have
registered for a Heally account.
Unsubscribe
link
Copyright (C) 2019 Heally Inc. All rights reserved.
Unsubscribe

#### own Example

I tried to send a minimalistic html email to myself containing this content:

```html
*dummy*
<div dir="ltr"><i>dummy</i></div>
```

and it worked just fine. Maybe the problem is an external class which does not get displayed/loaded and/or not exported by the gmail api

#### How I tried to display it

```html
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title>
    Current Email
  </mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content [innerHTML]="selectedEmail.mainContent">
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

I want to display emails like they get displayed in gmail instead I was only able to display plain text and basic styling through html tags.
I don't understand at which of my steps the styling gets lost or if I do not correctly display the emails.

Comment: What is the content inside `selectedEmail.mainContent`? can you post a sample one ?

Comment: Hey @programoholic I added an example content above

Comment: Could you add a mock-up example instead of this random spam?

Comment: I get my emails from a gmail account and I use the gmail api to export the emails from this gmail account to my database. The spam above is an example of what I want to display. As far as I can tell my problem is that I can't correctly display html emails because I am not able to extract everything through the gmail api. The above spam should be a html email instead it get's displayed as a plain text. As for a mock-up, I think the problem could be in the way I extract Emails. I could add an image how the above example get's displayed in my client if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular security Blocks dynamic rendering of HTML and other scripts. You need to bypass them using DOM Sanitizer.

Read more here : [Angular Security](https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis)

DO below changes in your code :

```
    // in your component.ts file

    //import this 
    import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    export class TestComponent{

    public htmlData :any ; 
    // in constructor create object 

    constructor( 
    ...
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer

    ...
    ){

    }

    someMethod(){

      /* this method must be called after getting the value of selectedEmail.mainContent 
   from service  */


     this.htmlData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(selectedEmail.mainContent); // this line bypasses angular security
    }
}
```

And in `compoenent.html`

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlData"> </div>
```

Here is the working StackBlitz :  [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwt3wr)

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Do you have an idea where I should sanitize my html content, because I work with phishing emails and the html will contain malicous parts.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it solved parts of my problem. I opened a new question for a problem resulting from this question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257871/how-to-fully-export-a-html-email-with-the-gmail-api-in-java

Comment: Although this obviously is working solution, I am wondering if that should be avoided anyway? Maybe embed the html inside an iframe?